# Is Amazon DocumentDB capable of using gridFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, gridfs, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am working with a client which needs grid-fs and wants to use a managed database service.  I am not familiar at all with amazon's DocumentDB and whether it is compatible with gridFS.  I could not find the question answered anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridFS is not currently supported.